# Question about sigma-algebra's

Tags: measure-theory

I currently reading a measure theory book but I have something I don't quite understand why is sigma-algebra iff its both a $\lambda$-system  and a $\pi$-system.
I am having troubles understanding why do we need it to be a $\pi$-system according to definition it seems to me to be only a $\lambda$-system ?

Here is the 3-definitions just in case:

1)$\pi$-system :

Definition: Let X be a set and let $\phi$ $\neq$ P $\subset$ of $2^x$ be a non-empty family of subsets of X. P is said to be a $\pi$-system if P is closed under intersection i.e if A,B $\in$ P --> A $\cap$ B $\in$ P.

2)$\lambda$-system:

Definition: Let X be a set and let $\phi$ $\neq$ L $\subset$ $2^x$ be a non-empty family of subsets of X. 
L is said to be a $\lambda$-system of L satisfies the following properties:

1)X $\in$ L
2)L is closed under taking complements i.e if A $\in$ L --> A` $\in$ L
3)L is closed under countable disjoint unions.

3)$\sigma$-algebra:

Definition: 
Let X be a non-empty set and $\Sigma$ $\subset$ $2^x$ be a non-empty collection of subsets of X. $\Sigma$ is said to be a $\sigma$-algebra on x if $\Sigma$ satisfies the following properties:

Same first two properties of $\lambda$-system along with the following property:

3)$\Sigma$ is closed under countable union.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A $\lambda$-system that is not a $\pi$-system might not be a $\sigma$-algebra**:

The reason is that you can't get all unions just from disjoint unions. Consider the following $\lambda$-system on the space $\{1,2,3,4\}$:
$$
\mathcal{G}=\{\varnothing,\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{1,3\},\{2,4\},\{1,2,3,4\}\}
$$
However, it is not a $\sigma$-algebra because $\{1,2\}\cup \{1,3\}$ does not belong to $\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Alright thanks alot I also see why now we need intersection aswell to get the sigma algebras ! thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

**$\sigma$-algebras are $\pi$-systems:**

Consider $A,B$ in a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$. Then $A^c$ and $B^c$ are also in $\mathcal{F}$. Since $\sigma$-algebras are closed under countable unions, the set $A^c\cup B^c$ is also in the $\mathcal{F}$. Lastly, $(A^c\cup B^c)^c$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}$. But by de Morgan's law, this is $A\cap B$.

Comment: what about the other why around which is my question why is lamda system classify a sigma algebra why do we need also it to be a pi system?